# Page reload doesn't work when removing # from angular urls

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to remove # from my angularjs urls using

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

and `<base href="/">` in my `index.html` and i have changed the hrefs in my partials from `#/abc` to `/abc`

it works fine when navigating through links within the site, however except my home page, on every other page, when i try to reload the page or copy and paste the link(and hit enter) it gives me error. i have done alot of search online with no luck. i'm hoping someone here has already gone through this and can help me. 
thanks

Comment: What server you're using?

Comment: @phikry node/express

Answer (score 0):

So if you are using jade you shall do the following:

```
app.get('/', index);
// while index is defined in routes.js and jade is defined as template engine
```

If you're using angularjs templating engine with normal html files, do the following:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
     res.sendfile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
};

app.get('/', index);
```

Comment: I don't use jade, i'm using angular template engine. i'm also not sure if second method works for angular app. i'm not supposed to use `.sendfile()` , routs are decided in front end and i'm just making api calls to get the content. but i could be wrong

Comment: yeah, as routes are decided in the front end you shall see the # but If you make it sent by the node server, it will be mocked to remove the #